# WooCommerce Shipping Fees Setup

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce for the first time to set up a book store and I really like it.  I do have a question with regards to setting up shipping fees.  Is there any way to set them up as per the table below:

```
-------------------------------------------------
No. of books |   UK  |   Europe   | Rest of World
-------------------------------------------------
1 Book       | £1.68 |   £5.15    |   £7.90
-------------------------------------------------
2 Books      | £1.68 |   £5.15    |   £7.90
-------------------------------------------------
3 Books      | £2.42 |   £6.60    |   £10.75
-------------------------------------------------
4 Books      | £3.30 |   £8.26    |   £13.90
-------------------------------------------------
5 Books      | £3.30 |   £8.26    |   £13.90
-------------------------------------------------
```

All time and help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of standard Woocommerce, but a plugin like [this](http://plugins.leewillis.co.uk/downloads/woocommerce-pro-shipping/) will do it for you.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as answered.